# XML structure getting modified while saving in to MarkLogic

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

I have a method implemented which takes xml contents as string parameter and write it to the MarkLogic using below code.

```
StringHandle stringHandle = new StringHandle();
stringHandle.set(contents);
XMLDocumentManager manager = client.newXMLDocumentManager();
manager.write("/testdoc.xml", stringHandle);
```

when i looked at the saved contents in MarkLogic, there is very big difference in incoming xml contents and saved contents.

For Example Lets assume i am getting following xml as String

```
<employee>
    <employeeName>employeeName1</employeeName>
    <contactNumber>contactNumber1</contactNumber>
    <address>
        <country>ABC</country>
        <state>PQR</state>
        <city>MNO</city>
        <street>IJK</street>
    </address>
</employee>
```

and after inserting it to MarkLogic i am seeing contents as,

```
<employee>
        <employeeName>employeeName1</employeeName>
        <contactNumber>contactNumber1</contactNumber>
        <address>
            <country>ABC</country>
            <state>PQR</state>
        </address>
        <city>MNO</city>
        <street>IJK</street>
    </employee>
```

here city and street elements are outside address element.

Please help me to resolve and to identity why this is happening.

Comment: Do you get the correct results using the MarkLogic Query Console? Lets say search for /employee[employeeName = "employeeName1"]? As you do not specify any transformation while inserting it shouldn't change. So there might be a error reading that document.

Comment: Thank you All for Replying on my questions, Now i Upgraded to MarkLogic-9 with Java Client API - 4.1.0 and I got Proper Output as i expected. Now XML is getting stored properly. I don't know what improvement they made in ML-9 Java API but now it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried changing your XML to general values ?? By this i mean try changing your XML format in a simple form- `change all the tags to ALPHABETS like <a><b><c> etc` If that resolves your problem that means you are having corelation between your `<address>,<city> and <street>` which is making it behave like this.

Comment: Thx @Shalini for your valuable Response but I cant change xml tags manually because at the run time i am getting xml having more than 1000 tags.

Comment: But at run time also you will be getting it from somewhere ? The feed xml- `/testdoc.xml`

Comment: Yes @Shalini, I am getting very huge xml from UI and i am inserting in to the MarkLogic as  /testdoc.xml, that's the reason it is not possible to rename all the xml tags.

Answer (score 0):

Is any transformation is applied to the ingestion process? Usually, by default, MarkLogic doesn't do perform any transformation. It might be possible just before insertion XML it is getting transformed to the new structure. 
How are you ingesting the document through put request or mlcp?

Comment: Thx @Sunil Chouhan for your reply, I am using MarkLogic Java api to write xml into Database.

Comment: @Shiv, can you please share code snippet (java api + marklogic) for insertion?

Comment: @ SunilChouhan code snippet is there in my Question, here "contents" is xml data as string coming from UI.